# Docker container stuck at (health: starting)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I added a new health check to my container like so:

```
 app:
      ...
       labels:
          - autoheal=true 
       healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", 'curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://localhost:3000/health --connect-timeout 30 --max-time 30 | grep 200']
          interval: 30s
          timeout: 60s
          retries: 3
       logging:
          driver: "syslog"
          options:
              syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:601"
       depends_on:
          - scalyr
```

but when i type "docker container ls" the health check is still starting:

"sh run-node"            11 minutes ago      Up 5 minutes (health: starting)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and in my case the problem was that I was using curl, which is [not installed in Alpine images](https://github.com/caprover/caprover/issues/844#issuecomment-702618580) by default.

Here is an equivalent `HEALTHCHECK` with wget (which is available in Alpine):

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=60s --retries=3 \
  CMD wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider http://localhost:3000/health || exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I increased the memory allocated to `4.00GB` from the default `2.00GB`. Just go to `Preferences` > `Resources` > `Advanced` then change the memory amount and `Apply & Restart`.